# long clean up time in rcpp function

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Have this observation that in the below rcpp function, somehow when it's run with type==0 (using std::unordered_map instead of std::map), the run times goes up non-linearly.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void cpp_test1(int a, int b, int type)
{     
  if (type==0)
  {     
    std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, NumericVector>> exposure_by_date_name;
    for (int i=0; i < a; ++i)
    {
      for (int j=0; j < b; ++j)
      {
        exposure_by_date_name[i][j] = NumericVector(68);
      }
    }
    Rcpp::Rcout << "done work " << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::map<int, std::map<int, NumericVector>> exposure_by_date_name;
    for (int i=0; i < a; ++i)
    {
      for (int j=0; j < b; ++j)
      {
        exposure_by_date_name[i][j] = NumericVector(68);
      }
    }
    Rcpp::Rcout << "done work " << std::endl;
  }
  return;
}
```

Here is how i capture the run time captured by system.time and the timing results:

```
for (type in c(0, 1))
{
  for (n in c(10, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000))
  {
    this_result = system.time(cpp_test1(100, n, type))
    this_result$type = type
    this_result$n = n
    result = rbind(result, this_result)
    print(result)
  }
}
print(result)


user.self sys.self elapsed user.child sys.child type n   
0.004     0        0.006   0          0         0    10  
0.152     0        0.151   0          0         0    50  
0.616     0        0.617   0          0         0    100 
2.624     0.008    2.631   0          0         0    200 
17.828    0.004    17.836  0          0         0    500 
58.844    0.06     58.907  0          0         0    1000
0.008     0        0.009   0          0         1    10  
0.004     0        0.003   0          0         1    50  
0.008     0        0.006   0          0         1    100 
0.012     0        0.013   0          0         1    200 
0.024     0        0.024   0          0         1    500 
0.052     0        0.049   0          0         1    1000
```

And what I also noticed the time doesn't seem to be spend in populating the map structure, the "done work" print out would got printed out pretty quickly, and majority of the time is spent in maybe some sort of cleanup.

Any one got some insight about the long wait time in cleaning up in the case of using unordered_map?

Comment: Are you testing an optimized or unoptimized build?

Comment: good question... i'm relatively new to rcpp i don't even know how to control it to build the cpp code optimized or not... how can i tell / control that and what's the default?

Comment: If you're looking for performance, I think I've read somewhere that it's better to use `boost::unordered_map` instead of `std::unordered_map`. You can get boost headers via package {BH}.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with an optimized build (`-O2`, visible by calling `Rcpp::sourceCpp` with option `verbose = TRUE`). It goes away if I use `std::vector<double>` instead of `Rcpp::NumericVector`).

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer to record my findings:

- I can reproduce the issue with both g++ version 6.2 and clang++ version 3.8, using `-O2` in both cases.
- It only happens for the combination of `std::unordered_map` and `Rcpp::NumericVector` or `Rcpp::IntegerVector`.
- Using `std::map` or `boost::unordered_map` instead of `std::unordered_map` removes the issue. As does using `std::vector<double>` instead of `Rcpp::NumericVector`.

Test code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

template<typename T, typename V>
void map_test(int a, int b) {
  T exposure_by_date_name;
  for (int i=0; i < a; ++i)
  {
    for (int j=0; j < b; ++j)
    {
      exposure_by_date_name[i][j] = V(68);
    }
  }
  Rcpp::Rcout << "done work" << std::endl;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void cpp_test2(int a, int b, int type) {
  if (type == 0) {
    map_test<std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, Rcpp::NumericVector>>, Rcpp::NumericVector>(a, b);
  } else if (type == 1) {
    map_test<std::map<int, std::map<int, Rcpp::NumericVector>>, Rcpp::NumericVector>(a, b);
  } else if (type == 2) {
    map_test<std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<double>>>, std::vector<double>>(a, b);
  } else if (type == 3) {
    map_test<boost::unordered_map<int, boost::unordered_map<int, Rcpp::NumericVector>>, Rcpp::NumericVector>(a, b);
  } else if (type == 4) {
    map_test<std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, Rcpp::IntegerVector>>, Rcpp::IntegerVector>(a, b);
  }
  Rcpp::Rcout << "function done" << std::endl;
}

/*** R
result = vector(mode = "list")
for (type in c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))
{
  for (n in c(10, 50, 100, 200, 500))
  {
    this_result = system.time(cpp_test2(100, n, type))
    this_result$type = type
    this_result$n = n
    result = rbind(result, this_result)
    print(result)
  }
}
print(result)
*/
```

Result:

```
            user.self sys.self elapsed user.child sys.child type n  
this_result 0.004     0        0.003   0          0         0    10 
this_result 0.096     0        0.097   0          0         0    50 
this_result 0.444     0        0.443   0          0         0    100
this_result 1.572     0.004    1.574   0          0         0    200
this_result 18.9      0        18.899  0          0         0    500
this_result 0.004     0        0.002   0          0         1    10 
this_result 0.004     0        0.004   0          0         1    50 
this_result 0.004     0        0.006   0          0         1    100
this_result 0.008     0        0.009   0          0         1    200
this_result 0.028     0        0.026   0          0         1    500
this_result 0.004     0        0.001   0          0         2    10 
this_result 0.004     0        0.002   0          0         2    50 
this_result 0.004     0        0.004   0          0         2    100
this_result 0.008     0        0.007   0          0         2    200
this_result 0.02      0        0.018   0          0         2    500
this_result 0.004     0        0.001   0          0         3    10 
this_result 0         0        0.002   0          0         3    50 
this_result 0.004     0        0.004   0          0         3    100
this_result 0.008     0        0.008   0          0         3    200
this_result 0.02      0        0.022   0          0         3    500
this_result 0.004     0        0.003   0          0         4    10 
this_result 0.096     0        0.093   0          0         4    50 
this_result 0.376     0        0.376   0          0         4    100
this_result 1.508     0        1.508   0          0         4    200
this_result 18.896    0.024    18.916  0          0         4    500
```

Comment: Crazy. What’s `sizeof (std::vector<int>)` vs `sizeof (Rcpp::NumericVector)` on your system? Is this causing different allocation/load factor strategies?

Comment: @KonradRudolph, `sizeof(std::vector<int>)` is 24, `sizeof(Rcpp::NumericVector)` is 16.